# Creating Truth Table with Python IndexError:list out of range

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, truthtable

Trying to make a Truth table through Python using itertools but keep getting same error

Heres my code so far

```
import sys
import itertools

def gen_constants(numvar):
    l = []
    for i in itertools.product([False, True], repeat=numvar):
        l.append (i)
    return l

def big_and (list):

    if False in list:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def big_or (list):
    if True in list:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    w0 = gen_constants (int(sys.argv [1]))
    for i in w0:
        print big_and (i)
    for i in w0:
        print big_or (i)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error comes on main() and on w0 = gen_constants (int(sys.argv [1]))

Comment: can you provide the traceback output as well?  What do you think could be causing the problem?

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine. I mean, I'm not sure if its doing what you want, but it prints a truth table...

Comment: mine isnt printing anything at all.....heres my traceback output

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\moody.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python32\moody.py", line 25, in main
    w0 = gen_constants (int(sys.argv [1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

`IndexError: list index out of range` means that the index supplied is too large for the list that you are indexing, meaning that when the line

```
w0 = gen_constants (int(sys.argv [1]))
```

is executed `sys.argv` contains at most 1 item, not the 2 that would make `sys.argv[1]` return a result, which means that you are not passing in an argument when running the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide integer argument.

Compare these:

```
$ python /tmp/111.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/111.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/111.py", line 24, in main
    w0 = gen_constants (int(sys.argv [1]))
IndexError: list index out of range

$ python /tmp/111.py 1
False
True
False
True

$ python /tmp/111.py 2
False
False
False
True
False
True
True
True

$ python /tmp/111.py w
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/111.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/111.py", line 24, in main
    w0 = gen_constants (int(sys.argv [1]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'w'
```

Or update your code to deal with any input or with the absence of one.

---

UPDATE:

```
def main():
    try:
        argument = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print 'This script needs one argument to run.'
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        argument = int(argument)
    except ValueError:
        print 'Provided argument must be an integer.'
        sys.exit(1)

    w0 = gen_constants (argument)
    for i in w0:
        print big_and (i)
    for i in w0:
        print big_or (i)
```

Which gives you:

```
$ python /tmp/111.py
This script needs one argument to run.

$ python /tmp/111.py 2.0
Provided argument must be an integer.

$ python /tmp/111.py w
Provided argument must be an integer.

$ python /tmp/111.py 1
False
True
False
True
```

Comment: Cant really tell what you did in the middle, but the beginnig and the end of the code is the exact same error except I get the IndexError instead of the ValueError

Comment: I run your script once with no arguments, twice with one integer argument: `1` and `2`, and once with string argument `w`. In this line `w0 = gen_constants (int(sys.argv [1]))` you assume 2 things: `1:` `sys.argv` has 2 or more items (first is a script file name, second - is the 1st argument, and so on), `2:` second item is an integer. This is why your script works if I pass integer to it, and crashes when I pass no arguments or a string/float one.

Comment: This is helping me understand the problem, but with no python background I dont really know how to go about fixing it. Anything you can tell me on how to specifically fix it? Where in that line do I pass an integer to it?